# google map api V3 javascript markers on click display

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Some troubles with the following code.

Works perfectly but I would display the assiociate legend in KML files to the makers when "click" on it...

I would like a general command, cause markers can be more than 500...

Any help ?

the URL : http://tequila357.wix.com/test-projet#!map/c161y

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var map;

// lets define some vars to make things easier later
var kml = {
    a: {
        name: "MAP BELGIUM",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=208899208399411894595.0004d24e3bd5bbd990f5d"
    },
b: {
        name: "GARDIENNES",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=3&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=208899208399411894595.0004d21a429f0f00d5400"
    },
    c: {
        name: "CRECHES",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=208899208399411894595.0004d22900ca6b246c6a1"
    },
d: {
        name: "CRECHES PRIV",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=208899208399411894595.0004d24cf21e2a254a10c"
    },
e: {
        name: "MAGASINS STORES",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=208899208399411894595.0004d24db929a46bae78c"
    },
f: {
        name: "BABYSITTERS",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=208899208399411894595.0004d24dba905263481df"
    },
// keep adding more if ye like 
};

// initialize our goo
function initializeMap() {
    var options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.5812, 4.5687),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

    createTogglers();
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);

// the important function... kml[id].xxxxx refers back to the top 
function toggleKML(checked, id) {

    if (checked) {

        var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml[id].url, {
            preserveViewport: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: true 
        });
        // store kml as obj
        kml[id].obj = layer;
        kml[id].obj.setMap(map);
    }
    else {
        kml[id].obj.setMap(null);
        delete kml[id].obj;
    }

};

// create the controls dynamically because it's easier, really
function createTogglers() {

    var html = "<form><ul>";
    for (var prop in kml) {
        html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
        " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleKML(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
        kml[prop].name + "<\/li>";
    }
    html += "<li class='control'><a href='#' onclick='removeAll();return false;'>" +
    "Remove all layers<\/a><\/li>" + 
    "<\/ul><\/form>";

    document.getElementById("toggle_box").innerHTML = html;
};

// easy way to remove all objects
function removeAll() {
    for (var prop in kml) {
        if (kml[prop].obj) {
            kml[prop].obj.setMap(null);
            delete kml[prop].obj;
        }

    }
};


// Append Class on Select
function highlight(box, listitem) {
    var selected = 'selected';
    var normal = 'normal';
    document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected: normal);
};

function startup() { 
// for example, this toggles kml b on load and updates the menu selector
var checkit = document.getElementById('a');
checkit.checked = true;
toggleKML(checkit, 'a');
highlight(checkit, 'selector1');
 }

// test legen

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng, map: map});

});

// end legend

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.selected { font-weight: bold; }
</style>

</head>
<body onload="startup()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;"></div>
<div id="toggle_box" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; right: 20px; padding: 10px; background: #fff; z-index: 5; "></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a "sidebar", that is not currently possible with KmlLayer.

You have at least two options:

- import the KML into FusionTables, use FusionTablesLayer to display the markers/polygon on the map, query the table in an onclick handler for the sidebar to open the InfoWindow.

  [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html)
- Use a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)

  [example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/WeeklyVolcanoGE-Reports_20100908-0914.xml)

To enable the InfoWindow to appear on click, remove this from the the code that initializes the KmlLayer:

```
 suppressInfoWindows: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I don't need any sidebar or menu like in your example. Just the the legend appearing on click like : https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/geoxml-kml

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. 

I don't need any sidebar or menu like in your example. 
Just the the legend appearing on click like :
 https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/geoxml-kml. 

The mouse "hand" is changing passing trough the marker so it will probably possible ...

Comment: I don't see any legend on [that example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/geoxml-kml).

Comment: Are you looking for the InfoWindow that appears when you click on the lines?

Comment: Thanks, that's what i want ! Perfect for now. And of course, Happy New Year